# Does move_base require Twist from Odometry?

Tags: navigation, odometry, rplidar, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to make a turtlebot like robot using only the RPLidar. Hence I donot have a good source for odometry. I'm getting the `Pose2D` using `laser_scan_matcher`, and can use the values and represent it in `nav_msgs/Odometry`.

I've also found a way to use these pose2D values with /scan headers to roughly calculate velocities.

But I want to know is it mandatory to have `Twist` information for move_base to work? Or does move_base only require Pose from the odometry messages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331081/does-move_base-require-twist-from-odometry?/) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2019-08-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

[move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) doesn't require any odometry as per the diagram in the document (couldn't get the image link to work). However, it is the [local_planner](http://wiki.ros.org/base_local_planner?distro=melodic) that requires information about your motion (specifically velocity so that it can extrapolate a dynamic path). I am unsure however, move_base might require a transform from base_link->odom->map. This should be done anyway if you have an odometry message and is definitely a pre-requisite before attempting navigation. Of course, the local planner is a part of move_base but I would segment it if you're implementing it so you can identify issues in a particular section.

Perhaps you could use [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to provide this transform and give an odometry message after accounting for noise. I have never used `laser_scan_matcher` myself, however, perhaps you could use an [Iterative Closest Point](http://wiki.ros.org/mrpt_icp_slam_2d) (ICP) estimate if you aren't happy with the results of the CSM estimate?

---

Originally posted by [PapaG](https://answers.ros.org/users/40565/papag/) with karma: 161 on 2019-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-08-23**:
Hi, yes robot_localisation should work too. I'm currently getting good results with laser_scan_matcher with a custom odometry node, so I'll continue playing around with that for a while. Thanks a lot! You've been great help!

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2020-04-18**:
@parvizal, could you provide a link to your custom odometry node? I take it you're taking odom from tf and converting it to nav_msgs/Odometry, using good-enough values for covariance? I'm doing exactly what you're doing (with an RPLidar as well :) ) and came to the same conclusion.

Edit: odom is only published in tf when you run the laser_scan_matching with gmapping demo :)
So I suppose you're just using the PoseStamped msg and v=(x-x0)/dt to get twist, and publishing that ..

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2020-04-18**:
Wrote this up as a base but can't test yet due to broken robot :/

```
    pose = data.pose
    ts = data.header.stamp
    #https://answers.ros.org/question/69754/quaternion-transformations-in-python/
    euler = tf.transformations.euler_from_quaternion(pose.orientation)
    yaw = euler[2]
    # different method
    #odom->pose.pose.orientation.z = sin(yaw_/2.0)
    #odom->pose.pose.orientation.w = cos(yaw_/2.0)

    dx   = pose.position.x   - self.prev_x
    dy   = pose.position.y   - self.prev_y
    dyaw = pose.position.yaw - self.prev_yaw
    dt   = ts                - self.prev_ts

    odom = Odometry()
    #odom.header = 
    #odom.child_frame_id = 
    odom.pose.pose = pose
    odom.pose.covariance[0]  = 0.2 # x, covariances here are likely widely off
    odom.pose.covariance[7]  = 0.2 # y
    odom.pose.covariance[35] = 0.4 # yaw
    odom.twist.twist.linear.x    = dx/dt    
    odom.twist.twist.linear.y    = dy/dt    
    odom.twist.twist.angular.yaw = dyaw/dt
```